# MSP430: Trying to learn interrupts using button and LED blinking

Tags: interrupt, msp430

I'm learning the MSP430 for the first time, and trying to teach myself interrupts.
I'm trying to follow these examples [1](https://gist.github.com/scsibug/948352) [2](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/noubir/Courses/CSU610/S07/MSP430-Clock-Timers.pdf) [3](https://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Class/e91/Lectures/E91(4)TimerA_Interrupts.pdf) [4](https://www.valpo.edu/college-of-engineering/files/2015/08/How-Do-I-Get-Started-MMB-011.pdf). 
I'm using an MSP430FR6989 eval board and writing the code in Code Composer Studio.

I'm trying to have the REDLED on the board toggle when I push the P1.1 button (ie, using an interrupt). 
I'm able to blink the LEDs using separate code, so I know the board works.
This is the code that i'm trying to get to work.

```
#include <msp430.h>
#include "driverlib.h"
int main(void)  //Main program

{
   WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD; // Stop watchdog timer

   P1DIR |= BIT0; // Set P1.0 to output and P1.3 to input direction
   P1OUT &= ~BIT0; // set P1.0 to Off
   P1IE |= BIT3; // P1.3 interrupt enabled
   P1IFG &= ~BIT3; // P1.3 interrupt flag cleared

   __bis_SR_register(GIE); // Enable all interrupts



   while(1) //Loop forever, we'll do our job in the interrupt routine...
   {}
}
#pragma vector=PORT1_VECTOR
__interrupt void Port_1(void)
{
    P1OUT ^= BIT0;  // Toggle P1.0
    P1IFG &= ~BIT3; // P1.3 interrupt flag cleared
}
```

When I press the button, the LED doesn't turn on and I'm not sure why.
I'd appreciate any help!

To show a working LED Blink program as requested by user @CL

```
#include <msp430.h>
#include "driverlib.h"

int main(void)
{

    WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD; // Disables the watchdog
    PM5CTL0 &= ~LOCKLPM5;     // allows output pins to be set... turning off pullups

    P1DIR = BIT0; // Make a pin an output... RED LED
    long x = 0; // Will be used to slow down blinking

    while(1) // Continuously repeat everything below
    {
     for(x=0 ; x < 30000 ; x=x+1); // Count from 0 to 30,000 for a delay
     P1OUT = BIT0; // Turn red LED light on
     for(x=0 ; x < 30000 ; x=x+1); // Count from 0 to 30,000 for a delay
     P1OUT ^= BIT0; // Turn off the red LED light
    }
}
```

Comment: Please look at TI's [example code](http://www.ti.com/product/MSP430FR6989/toolssoftware#soft) for the MSP430FR6989, especially what it does with LOCKLPM5.

Comment: Are you talking about disabling the power-on high impedance mode?
adding "PM5CTL0 &= ~LOCKLPM5;" after turning off the watchdog timer doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Start with a plain LED blinky program.

Comment: A working LED BLINK program is added as an EDIT

Answer (score 0):

On the MSP430FR6989 LaunchPad, P1.3 is not connected to a button. Use P1.1 instead.

The button requires a pull-up resistor, so you have to configure it in P1REN and P1OUT.

It might be a good idea to configure the signal edge for the interrupt in P1IES.

You have to clear LOCKLPM5 to activate the port settings.

All this can be seen in the `msp430fr69xx_p1_03.c` [example program](http://www.ti.com/product/MSP430FR6989/toolssoftware#softTools).